# TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

For some reason I can't get the range in the code to be read by the script I have written.  I have setup an IF statement that will return a "Yes" in the given range, if question A on the form is answer C, but the way I have setup its returning an error saying it can't read the range.

Please advise!

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Original Submissions");
  var lastRowNumber = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange(lastRowNumber, 28).getValue();
  if (cellValue == "Yes") {
      MailApp.sendEmail("gmail@gmail.com","Special Graduation Requirement","Visit " + sheet.getURL() + "to process the request.");
  }
}
```